# JavaFX View Navigation

Tags: model-view-controller, navigation, javafx-2

I'm working on a Desktop JavaFX 2 application. We're using FXML, an MVC architecture to build a tabbed UI. Now I'm struggling to find an elegant way for this scenario:

1. User clicks button on View 1, which is in a tab on the Main View.
2. Controller creates a new model object.
3. New model object is shown through View 2, which is opened in another tab on the Main View.

Would it be suitable to implement a class similar to GWT's `com.google.gwt.user.client.History`, handling all navigation request. First I'd have to register the main view. Or am I overseeing a JavaFX mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a tabbed web browser with history management which sounds a bit similar to your situation.  [The code](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/) is a bit of a mess, but you could look through it if you like to see if there is anything worthwhile there which is applicable to your situation.

For the next release (2.2) of JavaFX there will be a generic [pagination control](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19375) (anybody can register at that link to view the issue) which will probably help encapsulate some of the functionality you require as it mentions TabPane like functionality.

There has also been some [discussion of JavaFX history functionality](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2012-May/001594.html) on the [open-jfx development mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

The [jfx-flow](http://www.zenjava.com/jfx-flow/) project was created to enable weblike interfaces (e.g. views with history navigation) on JavaFX.  Not sure if it's completely developed for your use case, but you could take a look at that too.

Comment: Great links, thank you. So I will implement the functionality similarly, adapted to my program. It's too different from from a browser to use jfx-flow, but I think the direction is fine.